# How to deploy a "local" Rails app on a Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, appserver

I use Windows 10 and Rails 5
I'd like to deploy locally. I can not find what are the best appservers and how to do that with rails 5.

I don't like jruby or linux, so I can not use glassifish.

I did not find a good tutorial.

Comment: Do you mean "deploy" or setting up the application server and starting it ?

Comment: You can use the `puma` application server bundled with `rails`

Comment: Yes, but Puma does not have a interface like a Glassfish or IIS. Do you have another suggestion ?

Comment: Typically you wouldn't need an interface. You can do all the customisations you need in the `config/puma.rb` file. Read more about this here : https://github.com/puma/puma